# Representing a div as a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I want to show a list of various pets on my page. Each pet would linked to a javascript object representing that pet. This is the code for my `Pet` class:

```
function Pet()
{
   var id, name, var color, var photo;
   this.getHtml = function()
   {
      // Should return the html of a div representing the pet.
      return html;
   }
   this.buy = function()
   {
      //Find out whether pet is for sale, show a buy form, etc
   }
   // Snip
}
```

Using this object, I want to do this:

```
var cat = new Pet();
cat.id = 1;
cat.name = 'Cat';
cat.color = 'Black';
cat.photo = 'http://example.com/cat.jpg';

var dog = new Pet();
dog.id = 2;
dog.name = 'Dog';
dog.color = 'White';
dog.photo = 'http://example.com/dog400.jpg';

$(document).append(cat.getHtml());
$(document).append(dog.getHtml());
```

By running this code, I want to get the following two divs to be added to my page:

```
<div id="pet_1">
   Pet name: Cat <br>
   Color: Black <br>
   <img src='http://example.com/cat.jpg' alt='Cat' /><br>
   <input type='button' value='Buy This Pet' onclick = 'cat.Buy()';/>
</div>

<div id="pet_2">
   Pet name: Dog <br>
   Color: White <br>
   <img src='http://example.com/dog400.jpg' alt='Dog' /><br>
   <input type='button' value='Buy This Pet' onclick = 'dog.Buy()';/>
</div>
```

The questions I have are:

1) What's the best way to write the `pet.getHtml()` function so that it would produce the above output? I would really prefer to not store the html inside a string within my javascript, rather I'd prefer if a template div could be stored outside the javascript somewhere, and each time that div's html is retrieved, the necessary info inserted, and the html code of the new div is returned.

2) Also, certain elements within the new div (such as the buy button) should be linked to the object that produced them, e.g the 'Buy now' buttons of the cat/dog div call the `cat.buy();` and `dog.buy();` methods when clicked.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options here. You can either try a full blown client side MVC system for this. Personally I would recommend you look at [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) it's minimalistic and has a very lightweight `View` with no rendering/ui defaults.

Or write your own micro MVC system.

As for the views you can use a templating engine like EJS or jQuery tmpl.

An EJS view would be

```
<div id="<%= id %>">
   Pet name: <%= name %><br>
   Color: <%= color %><br>
   <img src='<%= url %>' alt='<%= name %>' /><br>
   <input type='button' value='Buy This Pet'/>
</div>
```

Then your code would look like :

```
function render() {
    var container = container || $("<div></div>").appendTo(parent);
    new EJS({url: view_url}).update(container[0], {
        id: this.id,
        color: this.color,
        url: this.url,
        name: this.name
    });
    var that = this;
    container.find(":button").click(function() {
        that.buy();
    });
}
```

As for jQuery tmpl

```
<script id="petTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div id="${id}">
       Pet name: ${name}<br>
       Color: ${color}<br>
       <img src='${url}' alt='${name}' /><br>
       <input class="buy" type='button' value='Buy This Pet'/>
    </div>
</script>

function render() {
    var that = this;
    $( "#petTemplate" ).tmpl( [{
        id: this.id,
        color: this.color,
        url: this.url,
        name: this.name
    }] ).appendTo( parent ).find(".buy:button").click(function() {
        that.buy();
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, an MVC system is what I'm looking for here :). How can it be implemented? Writing my own micro one seems best.

Comment: @ClickUpvote I would personally recommend you use backbone to achieve this.

Comment: @Raynos would you mind showing how this would be done via jquery templates? That'd be my preference.

Comment: @Raynos also, its possible that I'll have more than 1 button in the view, how would I select one one to use then?

Comment: @ClickUpvote use a class on your button so you can `.find(".class:button")`

Comment: @Raynos, when `cat.getHtml()` function is called, would `that` refer to the `cat` instance of the `pet` object? How does that work?

Comment: @ClickUpvote inside the `click` function `this` is the DOM element (the button). You want it to be the `cat` object instead. So you cache your `this` so that you can call `that.buy()` might aswell name it `var pet = this;` & `pet.buy()`

Comment: I'm guessing that the render() function you posted is going to be inside the `pet` function, in that case wouldn't the `this` variable refer to `pet` and not the instance of pet (dog, cat, etc)?

Comment: @ClickUpvote [this](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this). Inside the `Pet` constructor `this` references to the instance of `Pet`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at javascript templates. jQuery has a plugin in beta to accomplish this. [Here are the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).

There is a really good library called [Pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) that lets you integrate templates into a bunch of javascript frameworks.

Of course there are lots of docs on the subject [on Google](http://www.google.ca/search?q=javascript%20templates&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Any code to show how this would be done using Jquey templates?

Comment: Sorry forgot to put a sweet library to use templates with. I updated my response with a link.

Comment: an example using PURE with this model would be great.